# SSIS File System Task - Move Directory

Tags: ssis

I am extremely confused.

I have a destination directory: **\\Client\D$\Data Feed\Archive**. I set this as my Destination Connection in File System Task Editor.

I have a source directory: **\\Client\D$\Data Feed\Plan 24-01-2020**. I set this as my Source Connection in File System Task Editor. It also contains one CSV file.

For the Operation in File System Task Editor I choose **Move Directory** as the Operation.

All setup just click run. When I execute I get the following error message: "*Cannot create a file when that file already exists*."

Curiously enough the CSV file inside the source folder is copied to the Archive folder.

I was expecting only that the folder **Plan 24-01-2020** would be moved to the folder **Archive**.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Because according to this tutorial the folder should be moved without any issues: https://www.tutorialgateway.org/move-directory-using-file-system-task-in-ssis/

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things you'll want to do here.

First, create an expression in the `File System Task` that sets `OverwriteDestinationFile` to `TRUE`.

[image]

Next, you'll want to slightly modify your Destination path. Instead of just `\\Client\D$\Data Feed\Archive\`, you'll probably want to specify your destination as `\\Client\D$\Data Feed\Archive\Plan 24-01-2020\`. Otherwise, it will just copy the contents of `\\Client\D$\Data Feed\Plan 24-01-2020\` into `\\Client\D$\Data Feed\Archive\` without creating the `Plan 24-01-2020` sub-folder.

Comment: Thanks @digital.aaron. I got fed up with the stupid File System Task and used a script task + Directory.Move(source, destination)